# Understanding time series anomaly detection using Autoencoder

Tags: python, keras, time-series, autoencoder, anomaly-detection

I'm studying how to detect anomalies in the time series using an Autoeconder. In particular, I'm following the guide posted in the [Keras website](https://keras.io/examples/timeseries/timeseries_anomaly_detection/), but I don't understand why they are creating and how can I adapt it to my dataset. In their guide they load the dataset and create a sequence:

```
TIME_STEPS = 288

# Generated training sequences for use in the model.
def create_sequences(values, time_steps=TIME_STEPS):
    output = []
    for i in range(len(values) - time_steps):
        output.append(values[i : (i + time_steps)])
    return np.stack(output)


x_train = create_sequences(df_training_value.values)
print("Training input shape: ", x_train.shape)
```

The reason why they are using 288 as TIME_STEPS is because they have a value for every 5 mins for 14 days. My questions are:

1. Does this method split the data or is he just creating a 3D variable in the correct format for the Convolutional Autoencoder?
2. I have a dataset where there are stored the measurements of 30 devices. Each device has about 4000 values and it is structured as well:

   ```
    device01 0.02;0.13;1.15;0.10;8.30;........;4.20
    device02 0.06;0.13;1.40;0.03;7.40;........;6.30
    ........
    device30 0.03;0.24;1.10;0.43;4.40;........;2.30
   ```

   Since I do not have a timestamp reference in my dataset, how can I define the TIME_STEPS variable?

Comment: The sequence creation there has an implicit "hop" (how much a new window moves forward from the next) of 1 - which is the maximum one can have. If this creates too many sequences, one can usually increase the hop quite a bit - aka reducing the "overlap" between windows

Comment: Is each of the 4000 values for each of your devices a time-series, sampled at regular intervals?

Comment: @JonNordby Yes, each of those values is sampled every 3 seconds and it's the same for all the devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of TIME_STEPS in one sequence is more of a Hyperparameter. That you should try to optimize.

> *Does this method split the data or is he just creating a 3D variable in the correct
> format for the Convolutional Autoencoder?*

It simply create dataset for a 1-dimsnional convolutional network.Something like this,

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

Each row is an instance. Convolution will happen across the row.

> I have a dataset where there are stored the measurements of 30 devices

You may simply assume each data point as a Time-step assuming it was collected simultaneously.

But your data has an additional dimension i.e. Devices.

- So you should either build one model for each device or take the average of each device and consider it as the single time-step.
- Or you can apply a 1-D CNN with a 2-D kernel in your first layer, assuming each device as a channel. Check an example **[here](https://d2l.ai/chapter_natural-language-processing-applications/sentiment-analysis-cnn.html)**.
- In case, Keras doesn't allow a 2-D kernel, then use a 2D-CNN with kernel size "30xM". With that, the convolution will happen in only one direction.

   Beware that if you use the last 2 options, then your pre-processing function will have to change *i.e each time-step will have "30x1" as a dimension.*